# Stopping a WebBrowser causes Internet Explorer to be opened

Tags: c#, .net, browser

I'm using a C# WebBrowser in order to show a Facebook login dialog for my desktop application.
I'm regeistered on the WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted event, and once I get the URL I'm expecting, I stop the WebBrowser, and close the dialog.

For some reason, after closing the dialog, Internet Explorer suddenly opens.

I can only assume that it opens up IE (which is by the way, not even my default browser) because the web server returns the page, and my WebBrowser is already gone. Is that the case?
Any idea how to prevent it?

Thanks!

Edit: When I close the WebBrowser, it already contains the HTML that is displayed in the IE.

Comment: try hiding the C# webbrowser for a short time after receiving the URL then close it.

Comment: @Carl Thanks, that works fine, but if there's a way of preventing the wierd behavior without waiting, that would be even better :)

Comment: The code at the bottom of this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx mite give you some pointers.  They seem to call Dispose on the browser control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a popup. Why not just handle the event? You could do something like this.

```
{...
  WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
  wb.NewWindow += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(wb_NewWindow);
}

void wb_NewWindow(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the page did not load successfully. Maybe some script can't be executed by the browser.
Before you close `WebBrowser` or `Form`, where `webBrowser` is, open "zero page".
Do:

```
WebBrowser.url = new URl("about:blank");
```

then close form, close or dispose browser....